# How can i use Model c++ class in cascade with 2 other repeater in .qml file

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I have followed this tutorial : https://resources.qt.io/resources-by-content-type-videos-demos-tutorials/using-c-models-in-qml-tutorial

This was usefull to create my c++ class to manage my LightModel

Now I want to re-use this tutorial where I have a model inside 2 other repeaters in cascade. The issue is that my qml code instantiate LightModel objects inside repeaters so I don't have access to these instances from main.cpp

I used qmlRegisterType to give qml the ability to create several objects from my LightModel class.

main.cpp

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);

    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    qmlRegisterType<Light>("Light",1,0,"Light");
    qmlRegisterType<LightModel>("Light", 1,0,"LightModel");
    qmlRegisterUncreatableType<Light>("Light", 1, 0, "LightList", QStringLiteral("LightList should not be created in QML"));

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;

    MainWindow w;

    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));

    if (engine.rootObjects().isEmpty())
        return -1;

    w.show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

light.h

```
#ifndef LIGHT_H
#define LIGHT_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QVector>


struct LightItem{
    QString description;
    int value;
    int bornInf;
    int bornSup;
    int decimals; //1, 10
    bool enabled;
};

class Light : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Light(QObject *parent = nullptr);

    QVector<LightItem> items() const;

    bool setItemAt(int index, const LightItem &item);

signals:
    void preItemAppended();
    void postItemAppended();

    void preItemRemoved(int index);
    void postItemRemoved();


private:
    QVector<LightItem> mItems;
};

#endif // LIGHT_H
```

lightmodel.h

```
#ifndef LIGHTMODEL_H
#define LIGHTMODEL_H

#include <QAbstractListModel>

class Light;

class LightModel : public QAbstractListModel
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(Light *list READ list WRITE setList)
    Q_PROPERTY(int ledMode READ getLedMode WRITE setLedMode)


public:
    explicit LightModel(QObject *parent = nullptr);

    enum{
        DescriptionRole = Qt::UserRole,
        ValueRole,
        BornInfRole,
        BornSupRole,
        Decimals,
        EnableRole
    };
    // Basic functionality:
    int rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) const override;

    QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role = Qt::DisplayRole) const override;

    // Editable:
    bool setData(const QModelIndex &index, const QVariant &value,
                 int role = Qt::EditRole) override;

    Qt::ItemFlags flags(const QModelIndex& index) const override;

    virtual  QHash<int, QByteArray> roleNames() const override;



    Light *list() const;
    void setList(Light *list);

    int getLedMode() const;
    void setLedMode(int value);

private:

    Light *mList;
    int ledMode;
};

#endif // LIGHTMODEL_H
```

main.qml

```
StackLayout { 
    id: lampChose 
    currentIndex: gridLamps.indexImage
    Repeater { 
        id: repeater1 
        model: 24 
        StackLayout {
            id: lampStack
            currentIndex: tabBarNm.currentIndex 
            Repeater {
                id: repeater2
                model: 7 
                Column { 
                    id: columnSpinBoxtConfLeds
                    Repeater { 
                        id: repeaterParametersSpinBoxesLEDs 
                        model: LightModel { 
                            id: lightModel 
                            list: light } 
                        SpinBox { 
                            id: spinBoxTest 
                            visible: true 
                            editable: true 
                            value: model.value 
                            from: model.bornInf 
                            to: model.bornSup 
                            stepSize: 1
                            onValueChanged: {
                                model.value = value
                            }
                        } 
                    }
                } 
           }
     }
}
```

My LightModel class is implemented like ToDoModel in the tutorial exemple : https://github.com/mitchcurtis/todo-list-tutorial/tree/chapter-11

So the question is : how can I access from C++ the content of the LightModel objects because the 24x7 instances are created by .qml file.

Thanks a lot for your time

Comment: Hi there, welcome to Stack Overflow! I _really_ appreciate the inclusion of code and background of your issue. What is slightly bugging me, is the question at the end. `how can I access`. Can you clarify here? Access what? Access how? Individual objects of `LightModel`? I would love it if you could clarify this. Thanks!

Comment: The easiest solution (but maybe not the best) would be to register each `LightModel` from the constructor to the `LightList`. But it really depends on why you want to access the Lights. From the `id` it seems you are trying to create some sort of shop-gallery?

Comment: Hi, thank you both for your answer, 
@TrebuchetMS I would like to have the reference on the created objects because I want to do backend stuff with it. For exemple, this qml file create 24x7 instance of LightModel class, the user modify theses instances with the HMI, but I don't manage to reach these instances from c++. I don't know if you understand what I mean ?

Comment: @Amfasis, this will take a lot of lines in c++ file and a huge amount of lines in .qml file to register instances one by one and keep trace of them that way I think...

Comment: @C.Duval That I understand. That's your general overview, and its clear enough for me. But what I'm scratching my head about is what you want to do with the LightModels. And what do you want to access? Is it a specific slot or a specific member variable?

Comment: @TrebuchetMS LightModel contains a list of item with several properties. For exemple, let's say that I would like to register these properties inside a json or csv file. The aim of this program is to present a friendly HMI which controls values that can be entered and register them inside a file. Considering the amount of data I would like to use repeaters in qml. I am not fixed yet on the structure I will have in the backend, still, my goal is to register the data in a file

Comment: Alright, that helps me a bit. It would also help if you could describe _straightforwardly_ the process you want your program to take. I believe you want to trigger updates based on the spinboxes `onValueChanged`? --- So I think your question is (and correct me if I'm wrong), "Specifically, how to index the model appropriately when the value of a spinbox changes?" Especially with three dimensions of Repeaters. Is that what you're trying to ask by "access the C++ content"? (This is a guess, and I'm having a hard time trying to help without clear clarification.)

Comment: I think you actually should want to create the `LightModel`s in C++ (from csv/json as you say) and then fill the qml automatically from the C++ model. In this way you can also receive the signals in C++. This is called a ViewModel

Comment: And about your comment to require a lot of lines of code, I disagree. In the C++ side of `LightModel` you add one line, similar to `LightList::instance()->registerLightModel(this);`. This is called the singleton-pattern

Comment: Hi, I update the post to integrate my LightModel.h and Light.h
The updates are working fine because i can log and see model.value changing, but I have no way to see it from main.cpp
In other words : i would like to correlate the instances LightModel created 24x7 times and identify each one with both index of repeater1 and repeater2 (generated by "model :24 and model:7")
At the end I would like to have for example an array or a vector like :
`LightModel mArray[24][7]` which reference all the instances by index them.

Comment: Thanks Amfasis for your help,
Indeed, If I can fill my qml from c++ instead of qml create instance on his own it will help me. But I don't think that I want singleton pattern considering that I want to use the same class for 168 instances

Comment: I may have found a solution, I will stop using repeaters and just show the Model corresponding to the wished index. I was misslead by StackLayout and was taking the problem from qml to c++ but I will try to do the other way. In either case I get you posted. See you soon on the topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution to my problem : stop using repeaters with StackLayout.

My editable content is stored inside an array, set as context property inside my main.cpp and the view get the value corresponding to the current index

light.h

```
#ifndef LIGHT_H
#define LIGHT_H

#include <QObject>

class LightV2 : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit LightV2(QObject *parent = nullptr);

public slots:

    Q_INVOKABLE int getArrayValue(int indexLamp, int indexLight, int indexField);
    Q_INVOKABLE int getBornInf(int indexLamp, int indexLight, int indexField);
    Q_INVOKABLE int getBornSup(int indexLamp, int indexLight, int indexField);
    Q_INVOKABLE int getDecimal(int indexLamp, int indexLight, int indexField);

    Q_INVOKABLE void setArrayValue(int indexLamp, int indexLight, int indexField, int value);

private:
    QString mDescription;
    int mValue;
    int mArrayValue[24][7][6];
    int mBornInf[24][7][6];
    int mBornSup[24][7][6];
    int mDecimal[24][7][6];
};

#endif // LIGHTV2_H
```

main.cpp

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);

    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    qmlRegisterType<GeneralConf>("Light", 1,0, "GeneralConf");


    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    LightV2 lights;


    MainWindow w;
    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("lights", &lights);

    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));

    if (engine.rootObjects().isEmpty())
        return -1;

    w.show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

finally : solution in main.qml

```
Column {
            id: columnSpinBoxtConfLeds
            x:110
            y:0
            width:200
            spacing: 10

            Repeater {
                id: repeaterParametersSpinBoxesLEDs
                model: 6
                SpinBox {
                    id: spinBoxTest
                    property int decimals: lights.getDecimal(gridLamps.indexImage,tabBarNm.currentIndex, model.index);
                    property int decimalPresent:{
                        if (decimals == 10){
                            1
                        }
                        else{
                            0
                        }
                    }
                    width : 150
                    height: 25
                    focusPolicy: Qt.TabFocus

                    wheelEnabled: false
                    visible: true
                    editable: true

                    enabled: {
                        console.log("spinbox index:",model.index)
                        if (model.index == 2 || model.index == 3){
                            if(comboBoxMode.currentIndex >=1){
                                1
                            }
                            else{
                                0
                            }
                        }
                        else if (model.index >= 4){
                            if(comboBoxMode.currentIndex >=2){
                                1
                            }
                            else{
                                0
                            }
                        }
                        else{
                            1
                        }
                    }
                    value: lights.getArrayValue(gridLamps.indexImage,tabBarNm.currentIndex, model.index)
                    from : lights.getBornInf(gridLamps.indexImage,tabBarNm.currentIndex, model.index)
                    to : lights.getBornSup(gridLamps.indexImage,tabBarNm.currentIndex, model.index)
                    stepSize: 1

                    textFromValue: function(value, locale){
                        return Number(value / decimals).toLocaleString(locale, 'f',decimalPresent)
                    }
                    valueFromText: function(text,locale){
                        return Number.fromLocaleString(locale, text) * decimals
                    }

                    onValueChanged: {
                        lights.setArrayValue(gridLamps.indexImage,tabBarNm.currentIndex, model.index, value);
                        console.log(lights.getArrayValue(gridLamps.indexImage,tabBarNm.currentIndex, model.index));
                    }
                }
```

to conclude : this is how I managed to resolve my issue :

```
lights.getArrayValue(gridLamps.indexImage,tabBarNm.currentIndex, model.index)
```

and

```
lights.setArrayValue(gridLamps.indexImage,tabBarNm.currentIndex, model.index, value);
```